# Confused about type hinting in PHP

Tags: php

So consider the following example:

```
interface ViewBuilderContract {
    public function addFormName(string $formName): self;
}
```

Now lets implement this:

```
class ViewBuilder implements ViewBuilderContract {

    private $formNames = [];

    public function addFormName(string $formName): self {
        $this->formNames[] = $formName;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

As far as the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) are concerned:

> `self` The parameter must be an instanceof the same class as the one the
>   method is defined on. This can only be used on class and instance
>   methods.

Thats what I am doing by returning `$this` - according to the docs.

But when I run:

```
(new ViewBuilder)->addFormName('sample');
```

I get, which you can see [here - click execute code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd55d29e094ac5a58df3b544ad56cd6bf34372b2):

> Declaration of ViewBuilder::addFormName(string $formName): ViewBuilder
>   must be compatible with ViewBuilderContract::addFormName(string
>   $formName): ViewBuilderContract

Which doesn't make sense according to the docs. It should be a valid return. Do I just remove `self`? And if so why? and is there a way to stipulate a return value?

Comment: Though its interesting, it clearly says what's wrong in the error, self refers to ViewBuilderContract not self in ViewBuilder

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm so glad you can read. Now let's focus on the issue at hand of WHY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify `self` is returned in an interface.  See [this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39070492/5750032).

You could instead specify that the function return a `ViewBuilderContract`:

```
<?php
    interface ViewBuilderContract {
        public function addFormName(string $formName): ViewBuilderContract;
    }

    class ViewBuilder implements ViewBuilderContract {

        private $formNames = [];

        public function addFormName(string $formName): ViewBuilderContract {
            $this->formNames[] = $formName;

            return $this;
        }
    }
```

[Sandbox here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f6fd267cb07b3118d7bca608b0d30bd152150924)