# PHP Parent interface for interfaces with different return types in same method

Tags: php, interface, return-type, solid-principles

Lets start with some naive code:

```
class SettingFactory
{
  public function create($val, $type): Setting
  {
      switch($type) {
          case 'bool':
              return new CanDoSmthSetting();
          case 'multipleChoice':
              return new SomeOtherTypeSetting();

      }
  }

}

interface Setting 
{
    public function get();
    public function set();
    public function serialize();
}

interface BoolSetting extends Setting
{
    public function get(): bool;
    public function set(bool $value): void;
}

interface MultipleChoiceSetting extends Setting
{
    public function get(): array;
    public function set(array $values): void;
}

class CanDoSmthSetting implements BoolSetting
{
    ...
}

class SomeOtherTypeSetting implements MultipleChoiceSetting
{
    ...
}
```

There is some factory which create some Setting. There is predefined list of setting types, each type has its own behaviours, rules itd. I would love to work with return values and interfaces, however I do not know how. Idea with parent interface without type hints and return types just seems wrong.

How can it be done better?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068983/php-7-interfaces-return-type-hinting-and-self it may cover what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for your input @NigelRen, however it doesn't really cover my case or I do not see a point. I need to extend and override signatures of functions while keeping a parent interface which I can refer to. Linked question covers only return type declaration for same object, like object and its interface relation